# Indexing nodejs or browserify components with gulp

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, browserify, commonjs

I'd like to open source (via gulp-plugin) a simple build 'indexer' I'm using in a browserify project. Basically, I'm adding an 'index.js' file into every directory inside of a glob (gulp.src). Current index.js looks like this:

```
var index = {};

module.exports = index;

index.assets = require('./assets'); 
index.build = require('./build'); 
index.bundler = require('./bundler'); 
index.component = require('./component'); 
index.indexer = require('./indexer'); 
index.server = require('./server');  
index.database = require('./database');
```

Is this an okay way to organize a set of modules?? I'm also considering adding a node_modules folders to the top of my src dir (one level below the main dir). So instead of writing:

```
var form = require('./components).form; //or
var input = require('../components/forms).input
```

I can:

```
var form = require('form')
var input = require('input')
```

I find that this little indexer helps my workflow, maybe it'll help others too? But I don't want to put a plugin out there that's doing something potentially buggy. I asked the question to make sure that it's okay to index components like this, nested, that my syntax is correct, or if there are better ways to implement this pattern?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, looks useful. You should publish it and see what feedback you get.

Comment: yeah I should. I haven't used it in a while, so I've been manually indexing all my components (which is annoying). Only reason it's not published is because I haven't put in error handling yet

Comment: I did publish it, but it's not a gulp-plugin - https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-indexer

Answer (score 0):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-indexer

Not a gulp plugin yet, but maybe soon?